# Thymeleaf variable as a button

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm having trouble getting a Thymeleaf button to work. or even thymeleaf and jquery

I have users profile as /{username}

```
            <span style="font-size:12px" th:text="${indifriend.getAdded_user_id().username}" id="userOwnerPost"></span>
        <button th:onclick="'/' + ${indifriend.getAdded_user_id().username}"></button>
```

I'm successfully showing the username but it refuses to be anything other then text. been stuck on this for a minute

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your button to show up, it need to have some content.  Right now you're probably just seeing the text of the `<span />` and assuming it's your button (since your button has nothing between the `<button />` tags).
2. `onclick` expects a JavaScript expression.  A string value of `/username` won't do anything but cause JavaScript errors.

Something like this might work for you?

```
<button
  th:with="username=${indifriend.getAdded_user_id().username}"
  th:data-username="${username}"
  onclick="window.location.href = '/' + this.getAttribute('data-username')"
  th:text="${username}" />
```